# Fill in the blanks with either $∈$ or $⊆$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

So  was given a question that begins like this

1. Let $A=\{ \emptyset , 1 , \{2\} , \{1 , 2\} \}$ . Fill in the blanks with either $\in$ or $\subseteq$ .

$\{ 1 , \{2\} \}$______ $P(A)$

$\{2\}$______ $A$

$\{1\}$ ___$A$

$\{\{1 , 2\}\}$______ $P(A)$

For the second and third one I assumed the answer was $\subseteq$, but what I do not understand is what does $P(A)$ mean?

Comment: $P(A)$ is likely the power set of $A$, which is the set of all subsets of $A$.

Comment: @CC0607 so P(A) would the first one ∈ be , since it contains a subset of A and an element, and four would just be ⊆ ?

Comment: $\{ 2 \}$ is an *element* of $A$; thus, $\{ 2 \} \in A$, while $\{ 1 \}$ is not an *element* of $A$; $1$ is an element of $A$, and $\{ 1 \}$ (i.e. the set whose only element is $1$) is different from $1$. $\{ 1 \}$ is a *subset* of $A$: thus, $\{ 1 \} \subseteq A$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\{ 1 , \{2\} \}$ $\in$ $P(A)$

$\{2\} \in A$ (on the other hand $\{\{2\}\} \in P(A)$)

$\{1\} \subset A$ or you can say that $\{1\} \in P(A)$

$\{\{1 , 2\}\} \in P(A)$ because $\{1 , 2\} \in A$

I hope this clears you , what subset and belongs mean.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, $P(A)$ is the so-called power set of $A$. This means that $P(A)$ is the set of all subsets of $A$.

For instance, if I have a set $B=\{3,4\}$, then
$$P(B)=\{\emptyset,\{3\},\{4\},\{3,4\}\}.$$

Remember that $\in$ means "is an element of", and that $\subseteq$ means "is a subset of". Are you sure about your conclusion on part 2 and 3? For instance, if it were true that
$$\{2\}\subseteq A,$$
then every element of the left-hand-side set would be an element of the set on the right-hand-side. Since there is only one element on the left-hand-side, this would mean that $2$ is an element of $A$, or that $2\in A$. Is this true?